# Find the number of possible sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Three integers are given $X$, $Y$, and $N$. We have to find all the possible sums by taking $N$ integers at a time from the range $[X,Y]$. 
 Two of $N$ integers must be $X$ and $Y$.

For Example:

```
X = 13

Y = 15

N = 4

{13, 13, 13, 15} = 54

{13, 13, 14, 15} = 55

{13, 14, 14, 15} = 56

{13, 14, 15, 15} = 57

{13, 15, 15, 15} = 58

Hence answer is 5
```

Comment: *Numbers* ($\pi, \sqrt{17}, 3/91, \ldots$) or *Integers*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork X, Y and N all are positive integers

Comment: Simplify your problem:  Choose $N-2$ integers from $(X,Y)$ (i.e., not including $X$ and $Y$).  See why that is simpler?  And redefine $M=N-2$.  See why that is simpler?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried working this way but choosing N-2 integers from the range generates redundant sum like the sets :{13, 13, 15, 15} and {13, 14, 14, 15} have same sum  but different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible sums are the numbers from $(N-1)X+Y$ up to and including $X+(N-1)Y$, and there are $(X+(N-1)Y)-((N-1)X+Y)+1=(N-2)(Y-X)+1$ of these.